# <link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="../filename.css"> not working

Tags: html, css, href

I'm trying to link my css file into my html file using "../" but I do not have any idea why it is not working. can you please help me..thank you in advance.

Comment: is the css file in the parent folder above the html document? if not, thats why.

Comment: I'd guess you have the wrong path.

Comment: `../` is using relative path to where you are.

Comment: please define "it's not working" and share an example that shows the issue.

Comment: I have a separate folder named css where I put my css files..that css folder is inside the parent folder..

Comment: What are the full paths (after the domain) to both the page and CSS file? If there's a `css` folder involved, the path will have to include it -- `"../css/filename.css"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an absolute path to link the stylesheet instead of a relative path.

Per your comment above if you have a css folder that your css files are in, then that folder should be referenced in your path as well IE: "cssfolder/filename.css".

If you insist on using a relative path then coupling your css folder with the information you provided your link would be:

```
<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="../cssfolder/filename.css">
```

**Replace** '`cssfolder`' **with the name of your css folder**